# How to access Magento order 'visible_on_front' property?

Tags: magento

How to access Magento order 'visible_on_front' property?

I've tried the following bits:

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$order->setStatus('processing');
$order->setData('visible_on_front', 1);
```

or

```
$history = $this->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment('msg');
$history->setStatus('processing');
$history->setData('state', 'visible');
```

or

```
$history = $this->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment('msg');
$history->setStatus('processing');
$history->setData('visible_on_front', 1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and see if it has changed after you changed the data

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$order->setStatus('processing');
$order->setVisibleOnFront(1);
print_r($order->getData());
```

Comment: print_r shows it is set. However the order is till not visible in My Account. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Also tired to search for setVisibleOnFront function but can't find it. Can you please advise?

Comment: this is not a method it self but rather a magic set() method on object that adds things to object data array . to debug it further  grep 'VisibleOnFront' app/code/ -rsn

Comment: Life saving question: where can I edit this "visibletofront" thing because I have the same problem: orders are not showing in my account.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this need, I solved it like this:

```
$order->addStatusHistoryComment(<your comment>,<your status>)
      ->setIsVisibleOnFront(1);
```

Of course you load into $order the order you want to use.

With these you will have the comment visible into the user account page under the order details.

Comment: Almost forgot, remember to save the order object after you are done with your changes.